# Configure Realm in Activity

Tags: android, realm

According to the Realm documentation:

> The RealmConfiguration can be saved as a default configuration.
>   Setting a default configuration in your custom Application class makes
>   it available in the rest of your code.

Would I run into any issues if I init realm in my application class but do the configuration in an activity?

During realm migration, I rely on values returned during a network call made from our Splash Screen Activity and just want to make sure doing it this way won't cause any issues down the road.

Comment: You just make sure the `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration()` is called before `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`. then it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do the configuration in an activity?

That works as long as you do that in a `BaseActivity` of sorts, otherwise process death will kill you if you restore the app from an Activity that does not set the configuration.

---

Although you can be certain that the very first Activity that is open after a version update is the `Splash` (or ACTION_MAIN) so the migration would work there.

Are you using `Realm.getInstanceAsync()`?

Comment: I'm using Realm.getInstance().  And yes, the splash activity shows first in all instances (unless coming back from the background)